# Probability of a number N being reduced to a nonpositive value after K trials

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let's say we have an integer $N$. In each of $K$ trials, that number is reduced by a random integer number from the uniform interval $[0, M]$ (so if we had $M = 5$, then a number $N$ in each trial could be reduced by either $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ or $5$, each with a probability $\frac{1}{6}$). What is the probability that the number $N$ will be less than or equal to zero after $K$ trials? As an example, for $N=2$, $M=1$ and $K=3$ the answer is $0.5$.

I have to write the solution as an algorithm in some programming language, so the brute force solution would be to simply enumerate every permutation for a total of $(M+1)^K$ and count cases when $N \le 0$ at the end. But for this problem, $M$ and $K$ could be up to 1000, and then this complexity becomes $1000^{1000}$ which is intractable.

So I was wondering if there is some math formula that could help me avoid generating all the permutations?

Answer (score 1):

I'll think about the problem as adding from 0 to N, in steps of less than or equal to M.

Calculate the distribution of the integers you can hit, after 1 trial, and then, using that distribution, calculate the distribution after 2 trials, and so on. At trial n, you're doing at most order (Mn) calculations, so the whole thing can be done in quadratic complexity. There are probably better ways, and perhaps you can ask stack overflow.

EDIT: (With an example). (I'm on a phone so pardon the lack of formatting

If N = 1000, and M = 3, at each trial n, you should come up with such a table:

First trial (n=1)

0 1 2 3

0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25

For n=2, Consider each cell in the previous trial. For each cell, where can it hit?

For the 0 cell

0 1 2 3

0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25

For the 1 cell

1 2 3 4

0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25

For the 2 cell

2 3 4 5

0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25

For the 3 cell

3 4 5 6

0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25

Now add up all these probabilities and divide by M+1 = 4, to make sure the resulting sum is still 1.

Comment: Thanks. Could you perhaps give an example for the first two trials, how to compute that distribution for some small $M$, like $M=2$. I've never done something like that before so it's hard for me to visualize.

Comment: As a small extension to this, if M>n, then you can reduce the complexity by first computing the probability 'p' that more than (M-n)+1 of the rolls are a 0 (Since if we don't get at least this many zeroes we're guarenteed to have become non-positive). Then our final probability is (1-p) + p*(result from your algorithm on n-1 rolls).

Comment: @jimtahoe see my edit